# Drawing Crossed Ladders Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

i would like to add this figure in math.stack and for my document  by make it in latex

- How to make it looks in good-looking with different style

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-0.5,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
  \draw[name path=A] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (5,4.5)node[pos=0.8,sloped,auto]{\SI{10}{\meter}};
  \draw[name path=B] (0,3) -- (5,0)node[pos=0.2,sloped,auto]{\SI{8}{\meter}};
  \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={a}}];
  \draw[dashed] (a)node[right=1mm]{M} -- (a|-o)node[pos=0.7,auto]{\SI{3}{\meter}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you add some code to make this figure in left or right text

Comment: How do I put this figure on the left of right-aligned text

Comment: @Educ That qualifies as a separate question I suppose. You asked how to draw it! ;)

Comment: okay i will ask another question

Comment: @Educ You can use a `minipage`/`wrapfigure` etc. Please search in the site.